# Disabling and enabling Interactive Gesture Pop Recognizer on selected VCs only

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

So my navigation stack looks something like this:

A -> B -> **C -> D -> E -> F** -> G

I want to have the interactive gesture pop recognizer enabled on only from C to F (i.e. I don't want users to edge-swipe left while on **C** to get back to B and edge-swipe left on **G** to get back to **F**

My approach has been in the `viewWillAppear` functions of C and G, I disabled the interactive pop recognizer like so:

```
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
```

However this is not behaving like I intended.. Any idea?

EDIT: I'm using a total custom navigation controller where I implement my own "back button" logic... So I guess the real question is how can I get a callback when the pop gesture starts so I can call my custom logic.

Comment: What you mean with "However this is not behaving like I intended.. Any idea?"

Comment: What "custom logic" are we talking about? You still have not said what you are really trying to do. You've disabled the pop gesture on selected VCs only, and that is what the question is about. So there is no question to be answered.